# how to stylize the input checkbox in twitter bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have to make a input checkbox simple but could not find some kind of optional class at bootstrap, also searched on github some library and could not find anything simple as making foundation.

Thanks for help.

Comment: It isn't at all clear what you're asking for. Please elaborate.

Comment: Hes saying that the default check box style in Boostrap is an ugly grey box. There is no class he can add to make it look better.

Answer (score -21, accepted):

Just add an id(if it is just one checkbox) or class to that input element and define css for it:

CSS and HTML

'customId' would be the ID you give to the custom input tag:

```
<input id="customId" />

input#customId{
   background: #888 !important;
   border: none !important;
   color: #000 !important;
}
```

jsut overwrite whatver styles you want to...

IMPORTANT: just add !important to the end of a style to force an override

Comment: I don't think this answers the original question about checkboxes.  This code works for INPUTs (ie. text), but checkboxes aren't easily styleable via CSS like this.

Comment: How is this the accepted answer?! This doesn't work at all with a Bootstrap checkbox.

Comment: Not only that, adding !important at the end of each style declaration is a TERRIBLE idea and should be avoided whenever possible, favoring Cascading (after all, it's Cascading Style Sheets).

Comment: EVERYTHING is bad is this answer! Don't use ids in CSS, don't over-specify your selector (input#customId), don't use !important

Answer (score 2):

You can play with this to get a sense of what can be done:

```css
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');
@import url(//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css');

input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

.custom-check {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25px; height: 25px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 1;
 }

.custom-check::before {
  content: "\e013";
  color: #424242;
  display: none;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked+.custom-check::before {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  background-color: #554236;
}
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div>
  <label >
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span class="custom-check"></span>
    My Checkbox
  </label>
</div>
```

If that's not enough, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26532087/3196602) to a similar question also gives a good overview of the css involved in customizing the bootstrap checkbox.

Comment: Nice trick! However, in the snippet, the "My Checkbox" text move up and down depending on the checked state (this most likely have something to do with the baseline) adding overflow hidden to .custom-check solves that problem. Also setting line-height to 25px (or the same as .custom-check height) instead of 1 gives a better result...