# Creating a custom checkbox with CSS & Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, customization

I have the following mark-up using the bootstrap framework.

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="custom-container">
    <img class="center-block img-responsive img-circle invite-contact-trybe" src="{$img}" alt="Contact Image">
    <input class="invite-contact-checkbox" type="checkbox">
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to achieve the following:

[image: Checkbox design]

Is there anyway to do this using CSS?

I would obviously need 3 states:

Initial:

```
.custom-container input[type=checkbox]{}
```

Some form of hover state:

```
.custom-container input[type=checkbox]:hover{}
```

When it is checked:

```
.custom-container  input[type=checkbox]:checked{}
```

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css3-checkbox-radio/ there's quite a number of plugins, ideas, etc., for this. Google for it. Bootstrap is just css and js, there's nothing built in for this. The Bootstrap people particularly stay away from styling native elements.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

## Background image checkbox replacement

### Let's create this

[image: Screenshot]

This is a very simple example using a [`:before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) pseudo element as well as [`:checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked) and `:hover` states.

### With this clean HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" id="inputOne" />
<label for="inputOne"></label>
```

Note the matching `for` and `id` attributes, this attaches the label to the checkbox. Also, the order of elements is very important; the label must come after the input so we can style with `input:checked`

### As well as this Basic CSS

- The checkbox is hidden with `display: none` and all interaction is done with the label
- The `:after` pseudo element is given a unicode tick (`\2714`) but this could also be ticked with a background image.
- The jagged edge caused by the border-radius can be softened by a matching color `box-shadow`. The inside edge of the border looks fine when the background image is not a solid block of color.
- The [`transition: all 0.4s`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) creates a smooth fade in / out for the border.

I have added more guidance in CSS comments.

### Complete Example

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}
/* 
- Style each label that is directly after the input
- position: relative; will ensure that any position: absolute children will position themselves in relation to it
*/

input[type=checkbox] + label {
  position: relative;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocgp1.jpg) no-repeat;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: box-shadow 0.4s, border 0.4s;
  border: solid 5px #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #FFF;/* Soften the jagged edge */
  cursor: pointer;
}
/* Provide a border when hovered and when the checkbox before it is checked */

input[type=checkbox] + label:hover,
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
  border: solid 5px #F00;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #F00;
  /* Soften the jagged edge */
}
/* 
- Create a pseudo element :after when checked and provide a tick
- Center the content
*/

input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
  content: '\2714';
  /*content is required, though it can be empty - content: '';*/
  height: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  color: #F00;
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="inputOne" />
<label for="inputOne"></label>
```

Comment: Excellent answer, love the use of the new stackoverflow code snippet too! Thanks a lot, i'll post a link to my final solution here when i've implemented it. Thank you :D reputation++

Comment: I'm worried about hard coding the image using css.. Can you not use an <img> meta with this solution? I'm dynamically creating these checkboxes you see! :)

Comment: @Chris - You can place the background image on the label in the HTML using your variable like this: `<label style="background: {$img}">` and remove the current background image from the CSS stylesheet. That way your method of providing the url doesn't change :)

Comment: @misterManSam : can u help me with multiple images? when i tried this code, it works fine for single image but multiple image makes the first image checked, please help

Comment: @Rebecca - If you are still looking for a solution, you just need to rename each `id` and `for` attribute so that each checkbox input is matched with its label. [Here is an example](https://jsbin.com/qumaya/edit?html,css,output)