# Styling angular-ui-bootstrap checkbox (label)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui

I found this cool style here on stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26531642/creating-a-custom-checkbox-with-css-bootstrap/26532087#26532087) but I didn't know how to apply it to the chekcbox from  [angular-ui](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/buttons), well they're labels.

I tried adding them as classes, the effect has changed but the active class keep on messing up everything, and they looked weird.

Comment: can you post your code here...I mean what exactly have you tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working plunkr...http://plnkr.co/edit/6CFc73JZTWujUQWnTrWr?p=preview

Basically just add this CSS,

```
.btn-primary {
  background: url('http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-50-50-1.jpg') no-repeat;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.4s;
  border: solid 5px #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #FFF; /* Soften the jagged edge */
}
/* Provide a border when hovered and when the checkbox before it is checked */
.btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary.active,
.btn-primary:focus{
  border: solid 5px #F00;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #F00; /* Soften the jagged edge */
}
/* 
- Create a pseudo element :after when checked and provide a tick
- Center the content
*/
.btn-primary.active::after {
  content: '\2714'; /*content is required, though it can be empty - content: '';*/
  display: block;
  height: 1.5em;
  width: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  color: #F00;
}
.btn-primary.active{
  background: url('http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-50-50-1.jpg') no-repeat;
}
```

whereas in HTML,

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="singleModel" btn-checkbox btn-checkbox-true="1" btn-checkbox-false="0"></button>
```

Comment: but now all "btn-primary" all looks like that, is there a wat to change that ?

Comment: just add a class to your button for example `my-custom-btn`            ` and it will look like `<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary my-custom-btn" ng-model="singleModel" btn-checkbox btn-checkbox-true="1" btn-checkbox-false="0"></button>` now just replace all the `btn-primary` in the above CSS with the class `my-custom-btn`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I managed to get it working and replaced most of it.